# getting the value of text field executed through a for loop using php

Tags: php, loops

I have created 3 text fields which are displayed through a for loop. Now my concern is how will I get the values inputted to those text fields. Here's the code. Thank you.

```
<?php
echo '<form method = "post" action = "http://localhost:8080/sample.php">';

for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++){
echo '<input type = "text" name = "box"></br>';
}
echo'<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$square = $_POST['box'];
echo $square;   
}
echo'</form>';
?>
```

Comment: give these input fields different names and then just use $_POST['name'] to access the data

Comment: Would you mind telling me how to do that. I am confused since those fields are displayed through a loop.@**Lucia Angermüller**

Comment: just see the answer the user gave you, if you still have questions feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Lucia Angermüller  suggested you could do something like this

```
<?php
echo '<form method = "post" action = "http://localhost:8080/sample.php">';

for($a = 0; $a < 3; $a++){
echo '<input type = "text" name = "box' . $a . '"></br>';
}
echo'<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">';
```

and them you could access `$_POST['box0']` or `$_POST['box1']`.

Hope this helps. Good Luck :)

Comment: Also this could be even better if you create an array with the names of the input fields and then foreach the array names you create the  tag with the name you wish to set the input to. instead of a random number. ;) not sure if this will apply to your case but just in case.

Comment: @**user6694740** How about if I am using $_GET in my submit should I use $_GET as well in getting the value of ['box0'] ['box1']['box3'] or should still it be $_POST?

Comment: Each one is a HTTP Method, They are different and have their own characteristics. This is a link to a good read about their differences http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp . Use the same method on both places.

Comment: Noted.Thank you.@ **user6694740**